# basic search in laravel didn't work without error hints

Tags: laravel, search, http-status-code-404

i am trying to search data from table 'pegawai' by name, but when i try to search it, it show '404 not found', i try here and there but because there's no error hints now i am stuck.

this is the route

```
Route::get('/pegawai/cari', 'PegawaiController@cari');
```

PegawaiController

```
public function cari(Request $request)
    {
        // menangkap data pencarian
        $cari = $request->cari;

        // mengambil data dari table pegawai sesuai pencarian data
        $pegawai = DB::table('pegawai')
        ->where('pegawai_nama', 'like', "%".$cari."%")
        ->paginate(10);

        // mengirim data pegawai ke view index
        return view('index',['pegawai' => $pegawai]);

    }
```

view index

```
<form action="/pegawai/cari" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="cari" placeholder="Cari Pegawai .." value="{{ old('cari') }}">
        <input type="submit" value="CARI">
    </form>
```

the image above is what i try with the code, but no results.
what mistake did i make here?
and how can i get the search result i want without changing the method/code too much?

Comment: I would recommend using this notation `[PegawaiController::class, 'cari']` in stead of `'PegawaiController@cari'`

Comment: @Techno tried that, but now it can't run artisan serve. it said "trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given at E:\xampp\htdocs\belajar_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:562"

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I think you are using an older version of laravel then? Maybe add your actual version to the question, so others know what not to advise :P Anyhow, if you restore it back to `PegawaiController@cari` and run `php artisan route:list`, do you see your route in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you name your routes

So, your route will be like this

```
Route::get('pegawai/cari', 'PegawaiController@cari')->name('pegawai.search');
```

Then in your blade, you will call the route by its name.

```
<form action="{{route('pegawai.search')}}" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="cari" placeholder="Cari Pegawai .." value="{{ old('cari') }}">
        <input type="submit" value="CARI">
    </form>
```

**Possible Reason for your problem**

if you use a route in your blade (typical monolithic web app / website) without using route names, its possible to get the url / uri wrong **because** if you are already in a path (eg. `/user/profile`), and you write `/pegawai/cari` it possible the url path will be `domain.com/user/profile/pegawai/cari`  instead of `domain.com/pegawai/cari`
So using the route names will make the app write the exact path you intended.

In Laravel its called **Named route**

Link below

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#named-routes

Comment: sorry for the late response, thanks for the answers!